# How to make calculator over two activities

Tags: java, android, android-studio, calculator

I have made an app where the user selects a food type, enters a weight and then the app calculates the calories. This calorie is then moved onto the MainActivity (when the 'Save' button is pressed) where the total calories will be displayed for that day.

I need the app to take all calories calculated and add them onto any existing values on the main activity. I wrote the code below, however the app crashes when I press the save button my second activity.

```
String greeting = getIntent().getStringExtra("Greeting Message");
EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String value = editText1.getText().toString();

Integer aValue = (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) ? Integer.parseInt(value) : 0 ;
Integer bValue = (greeting != null && !greeting.isEmpty()) ? count +=Integer.parseInt(greeting) : 0 ;

editText1.setText(count + "");
```

**Stack Error:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nicola.student.mealtracker/com.nicola.student.mealtracker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "70.0Cal"
```

Comment: Please add the stack trace of the error

Comment: @Neil Please see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check Your value String, Your exception tells me that the String is "70.0Cal". First, You can get a substring, if You know that the last three signs are allways "Cal"

```
     String value = value.substring(0,substring.length()-3);
```

and second, You have a decimal value, so You should use not integer, You should use Float or double.

also, You should check if the text in the EditText is not null or empty:

```
     String edittextText = editText1.getText().toString();

     if(edittextText!=null && !edittextText.equals("")){
      //start calculating

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Either **value**, or **greeting** has a value that cannot be converted to int : "70.0Cal".
So remove the suffic **"Cal"** , and if you have to deal with fractions, use double instead of int.

Comment: On my second activity (where I'm calculating the food * weight) I have this: "editText7.setText(result + "Cal");". However if I remove the "+ "Cal"", I get the error 'Cannot resolve method 'setText(float)'. Any idea how I solve this issue?

Comment: concatenate your float with empty string ""

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the short stack trace provided I can see that you are parsing a `String` value that is not in a correct `Integer` format.

You will have to do some validation on the field to make sure that the input provided is a valid numeric value. You can do that by using the following method or by setting the EditText inputType `android:inputType="number"`

```
/**
 * Checks if the text is a valid numeric value
 * @param value
 * @return valid
 */
public static boolean isNumeric(String value) {
    if (!isNull(value)) {
        if (value.matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+")) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I would suggest not appending Cal to the value returned. Keep the input numeric. Rather add the "Cal" value in a `TextView` next to your `EditText`. 
Implement it this way by using the `isNumeric` method to check the value before parsing.

```
public void executeYourCode() {
    //Parse your values to Double 
    //as you are using Double values
    Double aValue =  getCheckedValue(value) ;
    Double bValue = getCheckedValue(greeting);

    count+= bValue;
    editText1.setText(String.valueOf(count));
}

public int getCheckedValue(String value) {
    if (value != null && !value.isEmpty() && isNumeric(value)) {
        return Double.parseDouble(value.trim());
    }

    return 0;
}
```